# Matplotlib Pie Chart Labels Alignment

Tags: python, charts, matplotlib

I was trying to create a pie chart in matplotlib and would like to put the labels within wedges. I used the following code to do it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(8,8), dpi=60)
ax=fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8])
labels = ['label0','label1','label2','label3','label4','label5','label6','label7','label8',\
          'label0','label1','label2','label3','label4','label5','label6','label7','label8']
colors = list('w' for _ in range(18))
fracs=list(20 for _ in range(18))
ax.pie(fracs, labels=labels, colors = colors, startangle=10,labeldistance=0.8)
plt.show()
```

It seems that the labels are not properly aligned within wedges as shown in the image below. Is there any way to modify(or rotate) the labels so that they can be shown properly inside the wedges?

Thank you!

[image: Matplotlib generated image]

Comment: You should ask exactly one question per question.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.pie

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adjusting the alignment of the labels after they are returned should do the trick:

```
patches, texts = ax.pie(fracs, labels=labels, colors = colors, 
                        startangle=10, labeldistance=0.8)
for t in texts:
    t.set_horizontalalignment('center')

plt.show()
```

I don't really understand the second question, as it seem you have already moved the slices by 10 degrees using the `startangle` parameter. It is typically better to list separate questions in different posts anyhow.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. As I moved the slices by 10 degree, I would like to label the degree number at the beginning of each slice. I will post this question separately.

Comment: This is the new question I posted regarding the second  question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645059/matplotlib-pie-charts-label-to-indicate-slice-angles  @hackyday