# Matplotlib customize pie chart labels and dropshadow

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart, label, dropshadow

I am trying to produce a Matplotlib pie chart in Python 2.7 using the example shown [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_demo_features.html). Here is the code I am using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# The slices will be ordered and plotted counter-clockwise.
labels = 'Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs'
sizes = [15, 30, 45, 10]
colors = ['yellowgreen', 'gold', 'lightskyblue', 'lightcoral']
explode = (0, 0.1, 0, 0)  # only "explode" the 2nd slice (i.e. 'Hogs')

plt.pie(sizes, explode=explode, colors=colors,
        autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90, radius=0.4,
        center=(0.5,0.5),
        frame=True, pctdistance=1.125)
# Set aspect ratio to be equal so that pie is drawn as a circle.
plt.axis('equal')

plt.show()
```

The output of this is shown below
[image: below]

There is some plot formatting related to labels and drop shadow that I am trying to adjust and would like to get some help with these:

**A.** The **label for the fraction 10% is much further away from the pink wedge** than the label 45% from the blue wedge. There seems to be questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642315/matplotlib-pie-chart-labels-alignment),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36204081/matplotlib-center-alignment-for-pie-chart-labels)) about this but the latest Matploltlib has too many values to unpack. So, when I use the answer from there:

```
patches, texts = plt.pie(...)
```

it throws this error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Is there a way to ensure that all percentage labels are equidistant from their corresponding wedge?

**B.** The **drop shadow is too thick** (or strong). I attempted to customize this with the `path_effects` argument from [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/patheffects_guide.html) using:

```
plt.pie(sizes, explode=explode, colors=colors,
        autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90, radius=0.4,
        center=(0.5,0.5),
        frame=True, pctdistance=1.125,
        path_effects=[path_effects.SimpleLineShadow(),
        path_effects.Normal()])
```

However, I get an error:

```
 TypeError: pie() got an unexpected keyword argument 'path_effects'
```

There seems to be a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258127/matplotlib-customizing-axes-shadow), but without an answer. Is there a way to manually reduce the thickness of the drop shadow?

**C.** I have specified a dictionary with the **font I would like to use for the pie percentage labels**:

```
labelfont = {'fontname':'Times New Roman', 'size':'14', 'color':'black', 'weight':'bold'}
```

For example, if I wanted to use this on the x-axis label of a scatter plot, I have been using this:

```
plt.xlabel('My_label',**labelfont)
```

I am trying to do something similar for the pie percentage labels. How can I specify that this font should be used for the percentages?

Comment: I recommend you if you ask several things, ask several questions.

Answer (score 2):

**A:**

From the [mpl pie](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.pie) documentation:

> If autopct is not None, return the tuple (patches, texts, autotexts), where patches and texts are as above, and autotexts is a list of Text instances for the numeric labels.

You need to unpack one value more. So you need to change that line:

```
patches, texts = plt.pie(...)
```

for

```
patches, texts, autotexts = plt.pie(...)
```

**B:**

As the `plt.pie` error say does not have a `path_effects` argument. You can loop over patches and set the custom shadow:

```
for patch in patches:
    patch.set_path_effects([path_effects.SimpleLineShadow(),
        path_effects.Normal()])
```

**C:**

You can use [plt.rc](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) for that.

Comment: Thanks. For C. I was thinking of using `pl.rcParams.update({'legend.font':labelfont})`. But, what should I use instead of `legend`? i.e. what are these percent labels called?

Comment: For A., I tried it. I used `for label in autotexts: label.set_horizontalalignment('center'); label.set_verticalalalignment('center')`. This allows me to horizontally and vertically move the wedge label. However, the topmost wedge label (10.0%) is still floating too far away from the wedge compared to the others. Is there any other way to reduce this separation?

Comment: For A: You can use `label.set_position((x, y))` , but it does not seem like a good solution. You can also increase the radius!